# AVAsset returns audio error even though there is a sound file

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avasset

I do the following which works fine

```
let audioCompositionTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))

let blankAudioUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "silence", withExtension: "wav")!
let blankAudio = AVAsset(url: blankAudioUrl)
let blankAudioTrack = blankAudio.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).first

var audioTrack: AVAssetTrack?

if videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).count > 0 {

    audioTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).first

} else {

    audioTrack = blankAudioTrack
}

do {

    if let audioTrack = audioTrack {

        try audioCompositionTrack?.insertTimeRange(myTimeRange, of: audioTrack, at: .zero)

    } else {
        print("audio track is nil") // never gets hit
    }

} catch let err as NSError {
    print(err.localizedDescription) // never gets hit
}
```

But when I had the *blankAudioUrl*, *blankAudio*, and *blankAudioTrack* to a function, the `do-try` keeps saying **The operation could not be completed**. The odd thing is I put break points on every return line in the function and `return nil` never gets hit. Inside the `do-try` the print statement *audio track is nil* never prints.

function:

```
func useSilentAudioTrack() -> AVAssetTrack? {
    
    guard let blankAudioUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "silence", withExtension: "wav") else {
        return nil
    }

    let blankAudio = AVAsset(url: blankAudioUrl)
    
    guard let blankAudioTrack = blankAudio.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).first else {
        return nil
    }
    
    return blankAudioTrack // this always returns
}
```

use of function in code:

```
var audioTrack: AVAssetTrack?

if videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).count > 0 {

    audioTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).first

} else {

    audioTrack = useSilentAudioTrack()
}

do {
            
    if let audioTrack = audioTrack {

        try audioCompositionTrack?.insertTimeRange(myTimeRange, of: audioTrack, at: .zero)

    } else {
        print("audio track is nil") // never gets hit
    }

} catch let err as NSError {
    print(err.localizedDescription) // Gets hit
}
```

Comment: Can you do `} catch  { print(error)  }`

Comment: That was a much better error, thanks! It printed: `error: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12780), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x283d83450 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12780 "(null)"}}`